# all sums from {0,1...n}

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So I am looking for all the sums from the nums ${0,1...n}$. We can use each number exactly once, we can add it or subtract it and the absolute value of each number must be greater atleast with 2,from the previous number.
example: 
$n=3$ All sums : $1 , 2, 3 ,-1 ,-2 ,-3 ,1+3, -1+3, 1-3, -1-3.$

So I tried using combinatorics, but I am guessing that this isn't the right way to solve the problem, because I can't find the answer for every $n$.

Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: What does "the absolute value of each number, must be greater at least with 2, from the previous number" mean? Shouldn't you be ok with $1+3-2$? Are you interested in different sum *expressions* or *values*?

Comment: well if heave the sum  x1+x2...xm;  | x1 | +2 <= x2

Comment: @Hagen, it looks like it means, you can do $1+3$, but not $1+2$.

Comment: Basically, if you use $k$ (with whatever sign), you're not allowed to use $k\pm 1$, as I read it.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether if, say, $n=4$, you can use $1+4+2$ or not. It talks about differing by at least 2 "from the previous number".

Comment: So, Simon, you have both 2 and $-1+3$ which equals 2. Do you want to count both, or do you count that as one sum?

Comment: i should count both .they both equal 2 but it's sum for diffrent numbers

Comment: and 1 +4 +2 is not a valid sum , |2| - |4| = 2-4 = -2, and   -2 <2

Comment: BTW, you first mention $\{0,\ldots,n\}$, but never use $0$!?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n$ denote the number of such sum expressions.
Such an expression for $n$ either does not use $n$ at all (so is one of $a_{n-1}$ expressions using at most numbers up to $n-1$) or is one of $a_{n-2}$ expressions using at most numbers up to $n-2$, followed by $\pm n$.
Thus we have the recursion
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2} $$ 
with $a_0=1$ (empty sum) and $a_1=3$ ("$+1$" and "$-1$" and empty sum).

As the solutions fo $x^2=x+2$ are $-1$ and $2$, we make the ansatz $a_n=\alpha\cdot (-1)^n+\beta\cdot 2^n$.  From $a_0=1$ we get $\alpha+\beta=1$, from $a_1=2$, we get $2\beta-\alpha=3$. Thus $\alpha=-\frac13,\beta=\frac43$, i.e., $$a_n=\frac43\cdot 2^n-\frac13\cdot (-1)^n$$
(or one less if you do not count the empty sum).
So for $n=3$, this gives $\frac43\cdot 8+\frac13=11$ (including the empty sum).